# Identify bulldozer truck -probably from early 90"s

Tags: set-identification

Have a bulldozer looking truck with green rocket boosters on it and silver arrows, silver knives on each side of the dome like top

- Colours: black green, clear green dome
- figure has clear green helmet, not an alien
- bulldozer on chain and lifts by hand...

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like [2161 Aqua Dozer](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/2161-1) from the Aquaraiders theme.

[image]